# How i can create Loop and timertask

Tags: java

i have a Little problem , im try make a loop whose  will be cooperate with timertask.
There is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int hp = 60;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random los = new Random();
        int pc = 1 + los.nextInt(4);
        Timer czas = new Timer();
        do{
            TimerTask zd = new TimerTask(){
                public void run(){
                    System.out.println("Czas off");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            };
            czas.schedule(zd, 5 * 1000);
            System.out.println("5 sek na odp");
            String odp = sc.nextLine();
            switch(odp){
                case "atk":
                    System.out.println("oo tak");
                    hp = hp - pc;
                    System.out.println("hp spadlo o " + pc + " "  + " wynosi " + hp);
                    czas.cancel();
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("zle");
                    czas.cancel();
                    hp = hp + pc;
                    System.out.println("hp wzroslo o " + pc);
            }
        } while (hp > 0);
        System.out.println("pokonany");
    }
}
```

And Im try make a sector where user input text and them from int hp is substraction random number, but user has only 5 second to input answer. This loop must  working at the time when int hp = 0

This is my log from console

```
5 sek na odp
atk
oo tak
hp spadlo o 1  wynosi 59
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer already cancelled.
        at java.base/java.util.Timer.sched(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.Timer.schedule(Unknown Source)
        at Main.main(Main.java:26)

[Program finished]
```

Comment: You are exiting the entire program when the timer runs out. Is this what you want to do? Can you better explain what you are trying to do, and consider renaming your variables so that they make some sense, so that by these names, your code becomes self-commenting and much easier to understand.

Comment: You are cancelling the timer in your code with `czas.cancel();` in the both cases. Is that what you intend to do? Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: Im try make a sequence , where user input  command "atk" with  this command  user substrac random number for int "hp" , but im try give for user a 5 seconds  to write this command. If user dont  wriite command in 5 second then his must get info about time "time left .. what else" and my idea  is when user input command, then he stole a random number from hp , if hp =0 loop and all sequense must stop working. Sorry for my English am now learnig , and im learning a java system . Best regards for all :)

Answer (score 0):

This is my code:

```
do {
            Random los = new Random();
            int pc = 1 + los.nextInt(6);
            TimerTask zd = new TimerTask(){
                public void run(){
                    System.out.println("Czas off");
                    System.out.println("5 sek");
                 }         
            };
        
            Timer czas = new Timer();
            czas.schedule(zd, 5 * 1000);
            System.out.println("5 sek na odp");
           
            String odp = sc.nextLine();
            switch(odp){
                case "atk":
                    System.out.println("oo tak");
                     hp = hp - pc;
                    System.out.println("hp spadlo o " + pc + " "  + " wynosi " + hp);
                         
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("zle");
                       
                    hp = hp + pc;
                    System.out.println("hp wzroslo o " + pc); 
                }
            czas.cancel();
           } while(hp>0);
           System.out.println("pokonany");         
}}
```

And now, I have another problem, everything is okay but, why `timertask` when run void, and then my loop is stopped? What I must change in my code to stop `timertask` and go back to my loop?

Comment: When time out , but hp isn't 0 them my code runnig public void run and my loop is stoped , i dont know  what im doing wrong, or how I can cancel run void ?